# How to drag and drop file from desktop to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

What I am trying to do is create a dropzone so the user can drop a file in it and send it the form. All the online examples I have seen all use AJAX to automatically upload the file. What I want to do is have the user drag and drop the file and have them click submit for the file to be processed and uploaded.

Comment: Have you searched at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

http://adodson.com/dropfile/demo-jquery.htm#source

Seems to me you just need to Google a little more and you should find quite a few of them.  I did.